# How to call the services within a mesh in ISTIO?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am using service mesh https://istio.io/ installed on top of kubernetes and have installed 
the example https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/, that ISTIO provides on their website.

Assume, I've created a service **FOO** and would like to call the service **ratings** through the virtual service **ratings**.

[image]

- How to call **ratings** within **FOO**? Which address do I have to
  provide the http client in the **FOO** service to call **ratings**. Do 
  Ihave to create a virtual service for **ratings**? **ratings** should 
  not be accessible outside of kubernetes cluser.
- When **FOO** calls **ratings**, will the request go first through the 
  own envoy proxy or it goes directly to **ratings** envoy proxy?

**Follow-up question**

Here are all virtual services installed on the kubernetes cluster:

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5etw.jpg)

The cluster IP address is:

[image]

The question is, how can I call the **ratings** service in **FOO** service? With the **Cluster IP** address?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How to call RATINGS within FOO? Which address do I have to provide the http client in the FOO service to call RATINGS. Do I have to create a virtual service for RATINGS? RATINGS should not be accessible outside of kubernetes cluster.

You can still call other services the same way you would without istio. Since the service only needs to be accessible inside the cluster, you'll want to expose it with a [clusterIP service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). You can then call the service by name using [Kubernetes DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/). In general, the service is available at `http(s)://{namespace}.{service-name}`. To call a service in the same namespace, you can leave the `{namespace}` out of the url.

While it is not necessary to create a VirtualService, [it is advised by istio](https://istio.io/docs/ops/best-practices/traffic-management/#set-default-routes-for-services):

> Although the default Istio behavior conveniently sends traffic from
> any source to all versions of a destination service without any rules
> being set, creating a VirtualService with a default route for every
> service, right from the start, is generally considered a best practice
> in Istio.

> When FOO calls RATINGS, will the request go first through the own envoy proxy or it goes directly to RATINGS envoy proxy?**

It will go through both envoy proxies. This is how istio can manage the routing of your requests and provide traffic insights like tracing.

The outbound envoy proxy can be bypassed though, with the [traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeOutboundIPRanges annotation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#direct-access-to-external-services).

Comment: I've changed my question.

Comment: I've added some more info about the Kubernetes DNS.

Comment: But I would like to call the ratings service through `VirtualService`, then I have to use the `ClusterIP` instead of `service-name`?

Comment: No, the service-name should still work when creating a `VirtualService` for it. Your services don't need to be aware that istio was deployed.

Comment: But I would like to call the `Ratings` service through `VirtualService`. How to do it?

Comment: This is automatically managed by Istio. If a `VirtualService` is registered for the service you're sending traffic to, Istio will intercept this traffic via the Envoy proxies and route it according to the configuration defined in the `VirtualService`.

Comment: What is the address of **RATINGS** service, for example `http(s)://{address}`, what do I have to put instead of `address`.

Comment: If you're in the same namespace, you can call it via `http(s)://ratings`. From a different namespace, you can call `http(s)://{namespace}.ratings`.

Answer (score 0):

use "mesh" keyword in the list of gateways of a virtual service, inter service communication will also use these rules by the side cars and essentially leverage all additional rules configured for a particular service(like, retries)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using [Kubernetes DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) that is attached to a [Kubernetes service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) that has the [selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors) for BOO service so that your traffic is redirected to BOO pods.